# How can I update homebrew and upgrade the new packages in one step?

Tags: bash, homebrew

I often run `brew update` followed by `brew upgrade`.

Can I do that in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by putting the following line in your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
alias brewu='brew update && brew upgrade --lock'
```

`brewu` can be replaced by whatever alias you want to use.